# Dynamically invoking super() with different parameters based on some conditions

Tags: angular, typescript, constructor, featuretoggle

I have a requirement where in I have a class in Angular that extends a Base class. Now, there is the feature Toggle Service that I am using to check for a feature.

If it is toggled on, I invoke super with param1 say super(param1)

If it is toggled off, I will invoke it like super(param2)

```
export class Example extends BaseClass {

    constructor(featureToggleService: FeatureToggleService) {
        let featureEnabled: boolean;
        featureToggleService.check('FEATURE').pipe(map(enabled) => {
            if (enabled) {
                featureEnabled = true;
            }
        });
        if (featureEnabled) {
            super(param1);
        } else {
            super(param2);
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason I don't think it's the correct way, but I have this requirement of invoking super with the param dynamically. Anyone got any views on this? Please share in that case.

Comment: Sounds like you need a factory or a strategy pattern here. Rather than trying to have one class trying to handle multiple features.

Comment: But you don't give any clue, a "logical" one I mean, about what difference is there between param1 and param2, i.e. between the two cases.

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio Param1 and 2 are object instances with different properties. I need to pass it dynamically based on feature toggle check.

Comment: That part is clear but it's a generic description and it is not enough to answer the question: whether what you are doing is legitimate or you should instead go "strategic" as VLAZ was suggesting, depends on *concrete* details and requirements, there is no generic answer there.

Comment: Already having an idea of what the super-class is actually doing, so what distinctions are relevant to it, could clarify.  But, conversely to what I have said previously, if you have requirements that are *not* any more specific than you have been telling so far, then a piece of advice might be feel free to code it in the *simplest possible way* that does the job...  --  BTW, I failed to properly ping @VLAZ before, doing it now.